# How to find a general formula for any number sequence? $19,25,45,87,159$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, power-series, generating-functions, interpolation

Suppose I have the following number series : 19,25,45,87,159

I want to build a formula for the nth term of the series.

Please help me with some algorithm which would solve my problem.

I tried to construct a generating function but i failed.

Comment: Declare that the full sequence is $$19,25,45,87,159,0,0,0,0,0,\ldots$$ and you can write down a simple formula involving Iverson brackets or Kronecker deltas.

Comment: @Henning Makholm The full sequence is 19, 25, 45, 87, 159, 269, 425, 635, 907, 1249, 1669, 2175, 2775, 3477, 4289, 5219.

Comment: Can You show me the steps please?

Comment: To restate (what I think is) @HenningMakholm's comment, questions of this form are ambiguous. There are many sequences starting that way, so you haven't given enough information for us to know which you have in mind. Presumably you want a "simple" such sequence, but in general simplicity is subjective (in this particular case Macrophage gives a defensible candidate).

Comment: 19, 25, 45, 87, 159, 269, 425, 635, 907, 1249, 1669, 2175, 2775, 3477, 4289, 5219, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...

Comment: Maybe, a polynomial !!!.

Comment: @David: there is no way to tell what the next term will be with any certainty, if the only information we have is the numbers in certain terms of the sequence.    Do you have some other information that would help tell what the next entries are?

Comment: $4/3 x^3 − x^2 − 1/3 x + 19$ is a good candidate.

Comment: @David I expanded my comment into [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2771771), which has some suggestions for improving questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$a_1=19$$
$$a_2=a_1+2\cdot3=25$$
$$a_3=a_2+4\cdot5=45$$
$$a_4=a_3+6\cdot7=87$$
$$a_5=a_4+8\cdot9=159$$

The recurrence formula is given by
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+2n\cdot(2n+1)=a_n+4n^2+2n,n>1$$
Now you can proceed to find a direct formula for $a_n$

The following terms are:$$19, 25, 45, 87, 159, 269, 425, 635, 907, 1249, 1669, 2175, 2775, 3477, 4289, 5219...$$

Speaking of a general algorithm, I don't think there is one. To show this, let's take the square root of any nonsquare number, $\sqrt7=2.6457513 $ for example...
And then we construct a sequence in which $a_n$ is nth digit after the decimal point. How can we ever extrapolate a general formula in reverse **if we don't know that we are taking square root of 7 in the first place**?

Also, as David said, for any finite sequence you can have infinitely many different closed-form formulas which give all the correct values you have, but diverge later on. That defies a general formula when you can only observe finite many terms of an unknown sequence.

Comment: I got this from computer: a(n) = 1/3 (4 n^3 - 3 n^2 - n + 57)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my question was to find an algorithm for any such sequence.

Comment: That cubic term makes sense! But I don't think there is an algorithm for any arbitrary sequence...

Comment: Okay let me ask a new question regarding that topic. By the way, dont you think that interpolation would work for any arbitary sequence?

Comment: No, see my proposed counterexample.

Comment: Half-facetious answer: run _all_ algorithms until you find one that matches the sequence that you have. Slightly less facetious answer: once you have enough terms of your sequence; you can find the simplest Turing Machine that reproduces the terms of it - which will often be shorter than the sequence itself, if your sequence is actually coming from an algorithmic source - and then continue running that TM to find the rest of the sequence.

Comment: Nice Argument, but for any finite sequence you can have infinitely many different closed-form formulas which give all the correct values you have, but diverge later on.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki That's interesting. But I'm not sure how you find the simplest Turing Machine. But obviously, speaking of "all" algorithm is unrealistic :D

Comment: @David Aha, I also just realized that, will add it to the main answer.

Comment: @Macrophage This isn't necessarily meant to be a _practical_ approach (and in fact, finding _the_ simplest Turing Machine that produces a given sequence is recursively unsolvable because it lets you solve the halting problem).  But the core notion, that of 'minimum description length' of a sequence, is an actual practical notion, and you can find a lot of information under that name.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general approach called "Lagrange polynomial" which ensures that there exists a polynomial of finite degree that passes all given finite plots $(x_i, y_i)$ (with distinct $x_i$s). Thus, we can set a polynomial $f$ for a given sequence $\{a_i\}_1^n$ that matches $f(i) = a_i$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$.

The strategy is not difficult. Let \begin{equation}p(x) = (x-1)\cdots(x-n)\end{equation} and $\displaystyle{p_i(x)= \frac{p(x)}{(x-i)}}$. If $i \neq j$, then $p_i(j)=0$. So, for $\displaystyle{q_i(x)=a_i\frac{p_i(x)}{p_i(i)}}$, $q_i(i)=a_i$ and $q_i(j)=0$. Thus, $\displaystyle{L(x) = \sum_1^n q_i(x)}$ is a desired polynomial.

For more details:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: The terms may not be in the form of a polynomial evaluated at positive integers...

Comment: Which terms do you point out? Lagrange polynomial may not be the best generating function for fitting a given sequence.

Comment: I mean the general term, it may not be that prescribed by the polynomial. As we can only fit with finite many terms.

Comment: Oh, I understood what you meant by.